# Preventing unwanted access

Tags: php

I have some code that is helping to protect some online surveys. The surveys have an incentive in the form of an Amazon voucher or cash (which is manually/semi-automatically distributed post-survey) so as you can imagine, we get a lot of people attempting to get multiple vouchers, or undesirable respondents mainly from China.

Of course the main way to prevent this, is to send out unique links to a set of pre-recruited people, however this isn't always an option and hence the need for some kind of protection.

Here is the code, I've removed 2 SQL insert queries to reduce the size of this post:

```
$countryCode = sanitise($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]);
$allowedCountries = getAllowedCountries($projectID); // array('GB', 'US', 'SE');

if(in_array($countryCode, $allowedCountries)) {

    // Count records with matching ip for this project, >=1 TRUE, 0 FALSE
    $isBlocked = checkForBlockedIP($projectID, $ip);

    if($isBlocked == TRUE) {

        header("Location: error.php?blocked");

    } else {

        // Count records with matching ip for this project, >=1 TRUE, 0 FALSE
        $isDuplicate = checkForDuplicateResponse($projectID, $ip);

        if ($isDuplicate == TRUE) {

            //<Removed>
            // Store identifying data into dup_attempts table
            // and block ip from further attempts

            header("Location: error.php?duplicate");

        } else {

            // Create redirect link and send user to it

            $redirectLink = $projectLink . $userID;
            header("refresh:3; url=" . $redirectLink . "");

        }

    }

}
```

I'm posting this here, because I'm not a professional developer and I don't know if I'm taking the right approach here. Perhaps my approach as a whole is wrong.

I'm allowing only certain countries to participate, checking for a duplicate IP (per project) and if one is found, then I'm storing it in a table for duplicate attempts and adding the IP to a blacklist for that project.

Comment: But with this IP blocking condition if 2 users are connected to the same network will not able to participate. 1st user can be 2nd can't;

Comment: Yeah that's true, I can't think of any more "specific" way to restrict it though. It could be a nightmare if everyone does the survey, collects the money then gets their "partner" to do it too, for extra money

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comment above about IP-based restriction perhaps not being the best approach here, or at least not using it as the only means to detect duplicates.

I think GeoIP is reasonable for blocking at a country level (though certainly not foolproof).

I think IP address might be a reasonable component to duplicate detection.  You could also add other duplicate detection mechanisms including:

- User ID (which is something you seem to have but are not using - I would think this would be most authoritative piece of information if there is authentication/login attached to this user ID)
- setting a cookie
- inspecting user agent
- setting value in browser localStorage and then have browser add to request (localStorage is a little harder for a typical user to clear out than cookies)

With regards to the code itself, you should get in the practice of inverting conditions when you have large blocks of code nested in a conditional (or really just in general to provide clear, early exit paths from a section of code).

For example:

```
if(!in_array($countryCode, $allowedCountries)) {
    // set location header and exit
}
if (checkForBlockedIP($projectID, $ip)) {
    // set location header and exit
}
if (checkForDuplicateResponse($projectID, $ip)) {
    // set location header and exit
}
// happy path code follows
```

There is no reason for your `else` blocks at all here from what I can tell.  As a general rule of thumb, the less nested code and code branches you have, the less prone your code is to bugs, so you should actively look to design away such constructs where possible.

Comment: Sorry for late reply - in regards to userid, this is is just an auto-generated id at the point of entering the survey. This is matched with an ID from the providers who send respondents to me, so they can track completion. Thanks for the tip regarding my nested if's, it looks a lot cleaner to 'screen' people out, than to make my code conditional. I'm very interested in learning how what I do, differs from real coders - I'm self taught and just use what ever worked first.. I think a cookie might be too easy to remove, but will definitely look into localStorage :)

Comment: @danielsmile If user ID is provided from a third party survey service, is there any reason it should not be authoritative with regards to user uniqueness (or at a very minimum a strongly considered component for your uniqueness check)?

Comment: Apologies Mike, a little hard to describe how it works in the comments. Not all respondents come from third-party services, and unfortunately many of those providers require us to reject fraudulent respondents, rather than do that work themselves. So we treat all respondents as if they are random members of the public, assign them a new id (regardless of whether they had one from a provider when they reached us, we store that + match it up later for confirming numbers with providers) It sounds complicated but if you saw it in action it's pretty simple :P

Comment: For example, you could sign up with a provider with a bunch of fake profiles, then access our survey through that. The provider will only check your email/phone number isn't already in use, but there are easy ways to work around that. Sometimes the incentives can be as high as £10-30 for an online survey, so it can be well worth manually creating false emails/accounts for "fraudies".

Answer (score 1):

```
    if($isBlocked == TRUE) {

        header("Location: error.php?blocked");

    }
```

Note that the example code in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) is

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
```

Calling `header` doesn't abort the request processing. You need to ensure that blocked requests are really blocked.

Comment: Sorry for late reply - I have edited the code slightly and forgot to add that it in. However, I am currently using `die("Redirecting to error.php?blocked");` instead of `exit;`. Is exit the more commonly used in the industry?

Comment: @danielsmile, I've only really used PHP professionally in one small company, so I have no idea what the relative proportions are in the industry. But since php.net says that `die` is equivalent to `exit` I draw two conclusions: `exit` is marginally preferable, but it's too minor an issue to waste time worrying about.